# SQL Server : query to get formatted string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to extract string in a SQL Server query?

```
declare @txt = ' TOWER LAKES 60010 *Friday, 10/17/1952 CLOUTIER FABRICANTE .'
```

I want to get `60010` and `10/17/1952` from that string.

I tried

```
select @txt 
where @txt like '[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9]
```

Any other way to extract that string?

Comment: There are a variety of ways to extract it. But _you_ have to think about what rules there are for extracting it before anyone can give you an answer.

Comment: yes.. but how to extract mm/dd/yyyy format inside that string value

Answer (score 0):

This is not well understood question on what exactly format you want to extract from the string values.

But, as your query suggests that also could achieve by using `patindex()` with `substring()` function to get fixed digits numeric values and date values

```
SELECT 
       substring(@txt, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @txt), 5), Numeric_Values 
       substring(@txt, patindex('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', @txt), 10) Date_values
```